# powershell script to read contents from Excel and send email

Tags: powershell

I have a Excel sheet having the details of mail ID, mail subject and mail content. I need to write a power-shell script. When it is ran, mails have to be sent to mail IDs present in the Excel sheet with the corresponding mail subject and content. Help me in writing a power-shell script. Even a ready-made code would be appreciable.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that you should have at least something. This is not the place where you will find someone who will write you the whole script.
to check the code and help you, yes, but not to write from scratch.
I would search on github for already written scripts, or Microsoft Technet Gallery: [Microsoft Technet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/)

To search the Excel file, first you could use **Get-Content**, and then use a **Select-Object** cmdlet to select the values you want.
After you find what you need, you can use **Send-MailMessage** cmdlet to send an email to recipient.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. i could do my scripting without your help @Vladimir